# NuGet only imports my .targets file into the top project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have multiple projects in my solution, they all have the same NuGet package installed. I installed this NuGet package via the 'Manage Nuget Packages for Solution' option in my menu.

Now this particular NuGet Package has a .targets file in my build folder that imports some files into the build.

When I rebuild my solution these files are only copied for the top-level project. The other projects don't get the files copied into their build folder. This is causing me headaches because all the projects need these files in their build folder.

When I look into my .csproject files I see the following difference:

**Project 1**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\NuGetTester.1.0.1\build\NuGetTester.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\NuGetTester.1.0.1\build\NuGetTester.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NuGetTester.1.0.1\build\NuGetTester.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NuGetTester.1.0.1\build\NuGetTester.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Project 2**
The 2nd project does not have these lines.

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

When I include these lines in the 2nd project everything seem to work.
Can someone explain why this only happens for the first project? Can I somehow force that every project in the solution that installs this NuGet will also include these lines? I can't force my users to include this manually.

Edit, this is the .targets file.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Versions\*.sql">
      <Link>App_Data\Versions\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you resolve this issue? Any update for this issue in your side?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I answered my own question. The order is not of importance. It appears to be a strange bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, to my knowledge, that the order of the projects was not the problem.
The problem only appears when I have no files in my target (net46) folder in the build folder.

Once I placed a random file into the .NET targetted folder the .targets file was imported into the project. Or if I removed all the .NET target folders from the build it works as usual.

So just to make a summary.

- Build folder with no .NET framework target folders -> It works
- Build folder with an empty .NET framework target folder -> Does not work
- Build folder with a .NET framework target folder filled with one or many files -> It works

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain why this only happens for the first project? Can I somehow force that every project in the solution that installs this NuGet will also include these lines?

Without install nuget package log, I could not give the reason that why this only happens for the first project. But you should make sure you have installed the nuget package to all projects when you installed the NuGet package via the '`Manage Nuget Packages for Solution`' option:

[image]

If all check boxes are checked, you still have this issue, you should install individually that package to the problematic project, then check the install log.

Just in case, there is a workaround for this issue. You can create a MSBuild project file named "Directory.Build.props" in the same folder as your solution with you content in it.
It will be primitive imported into all projects in the directory hierarchy.

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for the comment but it appears to be a completely other problem. I explained in my answer.